# What is the secret key returned by omniauth-provider for?

Tags: token, omniauth, secret-key

First, I know what a secret key is and what it's for, but I have a question about the instances in the following example.

When a user signs into your app using omniauth-provider, and you successfully get a response hash from an omniauth-provider, you get something like this

```
{
  :credentials => {
    :token => "a1b2c3d4...", # The OAuth 2.0 access token
    :secret => "abcdef1234"
  },
}
```

1) Now, are these two keys different from your application's token and secret token?

2) Do these returned tokens in the hash differ across each user, or are either of them the same for all users? (logically they should be different, but just trying to be thorough)

3) Are any of these dependent or tied in any way to what you set in your config file for your application keys and application secret keys?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, they are different.
2. They are specific to each user. Depending on the provider, they may also change with time.
3. It depends on the OmniAuth provider. Some providers give each user only one global token and secret, but others give each user a different token and secret per application. So depending on the provider, if you use a different app or if you change your config file, your user's tokens and secrets may change.

Comment: Thank you so much for your clarifications. So it's best to treat them pessimistically, since they may change. When you say my users' tokens and secrets may change, do you mean that if I change my config keys, the users won't be able to log in anymore, or that the keys will get updated when they try to log in after you change your app's keys?

Comment: The second one. But again, it depends on the provider. Make sure to investigate that provider's API so you know what you're dealing with.